# Floor Joist Penetration Repairs

Tags: joists

Any suggestions on how to repair this? All 4 penetrations are too big, but this top left one is particularly bad. I’ve looked at the engineered steel plates they sell online but those require 1.5” of wood below the penetration which I do not have. Do you think installing them anyways would cause issues down the road if we were to sell? Or any other suggestions to fix it?[image]

Comment: Or this? [How do I repair a floor joist which has a hole drilled less than 2 inches from the bottom?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/28178/35141)

Comment: Or this? [Repairing a notched floor joist](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/178768/35141)

Comment: Or this? [How to fix a joist that has been cut out](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/218749/35141)

Comment: That's effectively a deep notch, not a hole. You should be looking for notch repair kits, not hole reinforcement.